# get sum of value from object Typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript, calculator

I have this data,

```
    [Products, Products, Products, Products]
    0: Products {product_id: "1", Product_type_id: "11", Subtotal:450, …}
    1: Products {product_id: "2", Product_type_id: "22", Subtotal:550, …}
    2: Products {product_id: "3", Product_type_id: "33", Subtotal:600, …}
    3: Products {product_id: "4", Product_type_id: "44", Subtotal:100, …}
```

I want to `sum(Subtotal)` with this function but in html show nothing

```
 products: Products[] = [];

  public cartTotal(): number {
    let total: number = 0;
    this.products.forEach((e: any) => {
        total = total + Number(e.subtotal);
    });
    return total;
}
```

html code:

```
<label for="total">Totale: {{total}} </label> --> show nothing
<label for="total">{{cartTotal(total)}}Totale: ALL</label>  --> show NaN
```

Comment: Your data says `Subtotal` but your code says `subtotal` is this just a typo in the question, or the actual problem ?

Answer (score 0):

When you try to access a variable from html by `{{someVar}}`, angular will look at its component if an attribute called `someVar` exists. You are returning `total` from `cartTotal` but there is no one listening.

You have to change it to this

```
@Component({
   selector: 'some-comp',
   template: `<label for="total">Totale: {{total}} </label>`
})
export class SomeComponent {
    total;

    // you have to call this method at some point, 
    // I omitted that part. I assume you already call it.
    public cartTotal(): number {
        let tempTotal: number = 0;
        this.products.forEach((e: any) => {
            tempTotal= tempTotal+ Number(e.subtotal);
        });
        this.total = tempTotal;
    }
}
```

**Edit**

You should not call methods directly from your markup.

`<label for="total">{{cartTotal(total)}}Totale: ALL</label>` which will make angular call `cartTotal` so many times (at every change detection cycle). You would not want to go through `products` array and do the calculation thousands of times.

Comment: How to display this in html?

Comment: Totale: {{tempTotal}}  --> show nothing
{{cartTotal(tempTotal)}}Totale  --> show NaN

Comment: Yes but for me, I don't now why does't work. Maybe, because my Subtotal is form this result:  <input type="text" formControlName="Subtotal" id="Subtotal" name="Subtotal" [value]="(item.Unit_price * item.Quantity)">